# Using TPL with existing async APIs

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, restsharp

I want to use TPL with a existing API, RestSharp to be specific, so I can use continuations.

But this means I have to wrap a API that doesn't take the classical .NET approach to async, but instead implements callbacks. Take some code like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("service-url");
var request = new RestRequest();

client.ExecuteAsync<List<LiveTileWeatherResponse>>(request, 
    (response) =>
    {
        ...
    });
```

So here I want to wrap the ExecuteAsync in TPL, if it's possible. But I can't for the life of me, figure out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did TaskCompletionSource work with RestSharp?

Comment: Yes, it did. (That's why I accepted the answer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TPL provides [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) class which allows you to expose pretty much anything as a Task. By calling [SetResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449202.aspx) or [SetException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449189.aspx), you can cause the task to succeed or fail. In your example, you could probably do something like:

```
static Task<T> ExecuteTask<T>(this RestClient client, RestRequest request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, response => tcs.SetResult(response));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can then use it:

```
var task = client.ExecuteTask<List<LiveTileWeatherResponse>>(request);
foreach (var tile in task.Result)
{}
```

Or, if you want to chain tasks:

```
var task = client.ExecuteTask<List<LiveTileWeatherResponse>>(request);
task.ContinueWith(
    t => 
    {
        foreach (var tile in t.Result)
        {}
    }
);
```

You can read more about TaskCompletionSource at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx

Comment: It's definitively the right approach. But sadly, the ContinueWith is called to early, and the `t.IsCompleted` is set `false` :(

Comment: That does not matter - the delegate specified in ContinueWith will be scheduled and executed after the task completes, whenever that may be. t.IsCompleted should always be `true` inside the delegate though... Are you saying you are seeing it as `false` inside the delegate?

Comment: Nay, the problem appeared to be that I was calling `.Start()`, and the Mono implementation for WP7, did *not* warn me that it wasn't legal. (I tested with a .NET 4.0 console app, which told me it was wrong).

Comment: I made the same mistake as @Claus—I called `Start()` in a MonoTouch app and therefore the task finished before `TaskCompletionSource` had a chance to set its result.

Answer (score 1):

This was a major pain point for me when learning the TPL as well.

What you're looking for is [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx). When you create a `TaskCompletionSource`, it creates a special `Task` object (accessible by the `TaskCompletionSource.Task` property) which only completes when you call the `SetResult` or `SetException` methods on the associated `TaskCompletionSource`.

This post explains [how to wrap APM operations with the TPL](http://bvanderveen.com/a/async-with-rx-and-the-tpl-part-1/) (and also Rx). See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/750990#file_tpl.cs) demonstrating an APM operation wrapped in the TPL.